# Will my pages be crawled by google as they are Markdown files asynchronously interpreted and injected into the DOM?

Tags: laravel, web-crawler, markdown, google-crawlers

I am planning to start a blog so I created my own **laravel website**. My posts are **markdown** files with **.md extension**. When a user visits a post eg. **example.com/how-to-create-a-webiste** then my markdown file is fetched and parsed to generate html content and displayed on the **view** called **post**.

So actually I do not have any html files except for **post.blade.php**. So will this affect the crawler from crawling my website as I do not have html pages rather all my pages are markdown files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **NO**, Google or any other SE crawler will read the compiled version of your HTML, not your markdown files.

Google offers a tool to simulate crawling and even index manually your page, you will need to sign up in Search Console, check it out [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en).

You have to be careful with dynamic content tho, if the time it takes to inject it in the DOM is too high the robot may leave before the content shows up.

There are experiments, to test this theory, one that suits your situations is `Asynchronous injection`:

### Experiment

After a time out of 1000 milliseconds, the test writes a string into a DIV element.

#### Test content

For the test to be succesful, the following content should get indexed.

> Asynchronously injected content can be found in Google search, and this is proof: ngwzjcrnub

#### Result

Google definitely indexes this content.

[image: Experiment screenshot]

[Source of the experiment](https://centrical.com/test/google-json-ld-and-javascript-crawling-and-indexing-test.html)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The answer **no** may be correct for the question in the body, but would be wrong for the question in the title. That's confusing.

Comment: @Waylan Yes, you are right, it's not clear, I will submit an edit. Thank you.